# How to get text from a specific string position with grep?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I just want to get a text with grep from a specific string position. For example, there is a text who appears with a while loop (`cat file.txt | while read i; do`) :

```
Hello, how are you today?
```

How should I do if i just want to get everything in the right side of text after a specific string? (If i choose `how`, get `how are you today?`).

Bye and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression that matches the specified string followed by anything, and the `-o` option to `grep` so it only returns the part of the line that matched:

```
grep -o 'how.*' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed for this

```
$ cat file.txt
Hello, how are you?
$ sed -r "s/^.+(how.+)$/\1/" file.txt
how are you?
$
```

this used sed regex to anchor the text you want to start with - in this case, the word "how" and terminate when it finds the end of the line.